# How to capture SOAP messages from a Tomcat Java app to an external server?

Tags: java, soap, https, fiddler

I have a web application, which runs inside Tomcat6 and sends SOAP messages to some external system via HTTPS.

I want to intercept these messages.

In order to do this, I enabled HTTPS capture in the *Tools -> Fiddler options* dialog box.

[image: Fiddler options]

After I restarted Fiddler, I can see HTTPS requests to several hosts (like Google, Evernote) but not to the external system my Java app talks to.

Then, I added the JVM options `-Dhtttps.proxyHost=ipv4.fiddler -Dhttps.proxyPort=80` to my launch configuration and restarted the application. Again, no SOAP requests were captured by Fiddler.

[image: Idea configuration]

What can I do in order to view the SOAP messages (using Fiddler or some other tool)?

**Update 1 (22.10.2013 12:35 MSK):** When I change the JVM parameters to `-Dhttps.proxyHost=ipv4.fiddler -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=ipv4.fiddler -DproxyPort=80`  I get the exception `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.UnknownHostException: ipv4.fiddler` when the request is sent.

Comment: I don't know about all that fiddler MITM business, but https port usually 443, not 80.

Comment: @user1516873 Changing the JVM options to `-Dhttps.proxyHost=ipv4.fiddler -Dhttps.proxyPort=443 -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=ipv4.fiddler -DproxyPort=80` didn't help (`UnknownHostException`).

Comment: Using "ipv4.fiddler" is never going to work for registering as the proxy because that hostname only exists when the traffic is already going through the proxy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct JVM parameters were: `-Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888 -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DproxyPort=8888`.

Comment: It is not working for me. I added both http and https proxies but still I cannot see any soap call while I can see them in tomcat log.