# Configuring Tomcat to communicate through proxy in Localhost - Fiddler

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, proxy, fiddler

Tomcat is running in my localhost on standard 8080 port. When tomcat calls a service (soap/rest) running in the same server, I would like to capture it through fiddler.

Basically, any request that tomcat sends out, should be captured through Fiddler. Currently, it sends out request to another service running the same machine and that service in turn calls Amazon AWS, which I would like to capture as well.

Can anyone help? Note that this is opposite of traditional web request through proxy to the server.

I am open to any other alternatives as well.

Comment: Does this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512749/how-to-capture-soap-messages-from-a-tomcat-java-app-to-an-external-server not have your answer?

Comment: That DID help. Thanks much! I already tried these parameters except proxyset=true. Adding this one did help. Please post this as an answer, I will accept

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please have a look at [How to capture SOAP messages from a Tomcat Java app to an external server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512749/how-to-capture-soap-messages-from-a-tomcat-java-app-to-an-external-server) for information on setting the proxy for Tomcat.

The correct JVM parameters should look like: `-Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888 -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DproxyPort=8888`