# Capture Amazon S3 requests from Tomcat using fiddler

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, request, fiddler, capture

My web application sitting in tomcat reads the files in Amazon S3 buckets. Is there a way to capture the request? I am not sure what protocol it uses. (s3?) I would like to capture this request using fiddler.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, S3 typically uses HTTP/HTTPS for communication ([REST, SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3)). Are you using a library to make your S3 calls? The library may not use the default proxy.

As you know, [Configuring Tomcat to communicate through proxy in Localhost - Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23484911/configuring-tomcat-to-communicate-through-proxy-in-localhost-fiddler) has general details on how to configure Tomcat to use the Fiddler proxy.