# Not able to make CFHTTP call in ColdFusion

Tags: web-services, coldfusion

I am trying to call `CFHTTP` from ColdFusion but it's not working.

```
<cfhttp url="https://apracareers.localhost/be/index.cfm?event=apm.ExecuteRuleAndActionInApmApi&testExecID=1CCDBEBA-3892-8ED2-F158-A42B9D79317F"  method="POST" resolveurl="no" charset="utf-8" >  
    <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="*"> 
</cfhttp>
```

In the log I am getting:

> May 14, 2018 14:04:13 PM Information [A9ACF8BE-FFAD-0210-F70213D0E7DEF338] - Starting HTTP request {URL='https://apracareers.localhost/be/index.cfm?event=apm.ExecuteRuleAndActionInApmApi&testExecID=1CCDBEBA-3892-8ED2-F158-A42B9D79317F', method='POST'}

Comment: Did you try `<cfdump var="#cfhttp#">` after the call?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "it's not working."?  What was the actual result and what did you expect instead?

Comment: Big chance you did not install the ssl certificate. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37322536/2482184

Answer (score 1):

If you're running this in an environment where proxyserver is set, you may want to add the proxyserver and proxyport in your cfhttp tag.

```
<cfhttp url="yourURL" method="post" proxyserver="xproxy.what.ever"  result="httpResult" proxyport="8080" >
 <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="*"> 
</cfhttp>
```